# Apps Link android is not opening to my app when i select browser from the dialog even app is installed

Tags: android, android-app-links

```
I have done all the steps from the blog
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.
After that, if I click on the link it is showing my app and chrome as an option to select, if I select chrome instead of opening the app it is taking to play store.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , this worked for me . Add this in your main activity or the activity you want to open with this link .

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>

<data
    android:host="www.my.app.com"
    android:path="launch"
    android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```